# laravel apache server issue

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am getting AWS apache following issues
ERROR
BadMethodCallException
HELP
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isCustomerEmailIdUnique()

this is model function

```
public function isCustomerEmailIdUnique($email,$customerId)
{
    $dataCustomerId = DB::table($this->table)->where('email_id',$email)->get(['customer_id']);
    // If customerId of email exist , return true. if email id not exist return false

     $data = json_decode(json_encode($dataCustomerId), true);       
     if(empty( $data) || $data['customer_id'] == $customerId ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why json_decode(json_encode($dataCustomerId), true); ?

Comment: if i remove still it is giving same error

Comment: It is perfect working on window machine. It is not working on server

Comment: command --> php artisan clear-compiled